# C# TCP connecting to a computer

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp

After some research I've almost managed to get a program to connect to another PC using TCP.

I've made 2 programs :

1. one to connect and
2. one to receive which goes on the other computer if that makes sense.

I'm not sure if I use my public IP address to connect but it doesn't work.

I'm not sure if its the program or the wrong IP.

So here is the code for the program that connects.

```
    public static bool IsConnected;
    public static NetworkStream Writer;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.Title = "Offline";
        TcpClient Connector = new TcpClient();

    GetConnection:

        Console.WriteLine("Enter server IP :");
        string IP = Console.ReadLine();

        try
        {
            Connector.Connect(IP, 2001);
            IsConnected = true;
            Console.Title = "Online";
            Writer = Connector.GetStream();
        }
        catch
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error connecting to target server! Press any key to try again.");
            Console.ReadKey();
            Console.Clear();
            goto GetConnection;
        }
```

Its a console application where I just type in the ip address and it tells me if its connected or not,

It uses port 2001 just like the receiver which the code for that is below.

```
    public static NetworkStream Receiver;
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        FreeConsole();

        TcpListener l = new TcpListener (2001);

        l.Start();
        TcpClient Connection = l.AcceptTcpClient();
        Receiver = Connection.GetStream();
    }
```

If anyone has any ideas as to why it doesn't connect its appriciated

Comment: There's all kinds of reason why it might not connect.  Can you ping the ip address from one machine to the other?

Comment: well its the same ip address because its my other computer but i can try that

Comment: You have two different machines with the same ip address?  Thats not going to work.

Comment: oh that might be why, thats going to be difficult to test now, any ideas?

Comment: Just give each one a different ip address on the same sub net eg 172.1.1.1 and 172.1.1.2 - then check you can ping one machine from the other.  If you can do that then opening a TCP socket should work fine.

Comment: do you have a link or anything on how i would do that? its a university network so i dont think i can go into their settings or anything. im not good at networking at all

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107810/discussion-between-afrogonabike-and-will).

Answer (score 1):

I was using the public ip address instead of the ipv4 address

Comment: Usually `Public IP == IPv4`. IPv4 is just _Internet Protocol version 4_, it can be both public and private. :)